# How to test if one element from list is in other list in django filter

Tags: python, django

I trying to make this for query work using the Django filter. Any help?

```
tmp = TemporaryLesson.objects.filter(Q(expiration_date__gte=now()) | Q(expiration_date__isnull=True))
temporary_lessons = []
for t in tmp:  # How to make this manual query works in the filter above?
    for c in t.related_courses:
        if c in student.my_courses:
            temporary_lessons.append(t)
            break
```

EDIT: 
Model variables

From Student

```
my_courses = models.ManyToManyField(
    'course.BaseCourse', 
    related_name='students', 
    through=CourseXStudent
)
```

From TemporaryLesson

```
related_courses = models.ManyToManyField(
    'course.BaseCourse',
    related_name='temporary_lessons'
)
```

Comment: please show your models.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What "manual query"?

Comment: manual means: outside database, inside server